# Possible ID different is same name to CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So i need use Hide elements (id or class) any name is "dialog"

Look a example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 for (x=0;x<$("div").length;x++) {
  var sa_string = $("div:nth("+x+")").attr("id");
  if (sa_string.substring(0,6) == "dialog") { console.log($("div#"+sa_string).hide()); }
 }
});
```

```css
body {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: black 0px 2px 3px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div id="dialogYB1W7" style="background: red;">
 <div id="text1">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text1">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text1">bla bla bla</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="description1AO2" style="background: green;">
 <div id="text1">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text2">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text3">bla bla bla</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="description4T6W" style="background: blue;">
 <div id="text1">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text2">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text3">bla bla bla</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="dialogB3EW" style="background: yellow;">
 <div id="text1">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text2">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text3">bla bla bla</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="dialog1L2A" style="background: red;">
 <div id="text1">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text2">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text3">bla bla bla</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="descriptionY3L1" style="background: green;">
 <div id="text1">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text2">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text3">bla bla bla</div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

I try css  `$('div[id=dialog*]').hide()` is not working .. i know is wrong!

But possible or impossible? just jquery =( and i love CSS to work Adblock

Sorry bad english! Thanks

Comment: `$('div[id^="dialog"]')` Should work

Comment: Have a look at the [different attribute selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) available in jQuery

Comment: You should use class instead

Comment: AWolff, about adblock.. sorry not is my website

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('div[id^="dialog"]')` should work.

`^=` is the starts with selector

Comment: Basically. So you can use `[id$="something"]` as an ends with and `[id*="something"]` as a contains selector

Comment: @KingRider If this one solves your problem please don't forget to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can simple use:

```
$("div[id^=dialog]").hide();
```

Hides all `div` elements that id attribute starts with `dialog`.

```js
$("div[id^=dialog]").hide();
```

```css
body {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: black 0px 2px 3px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div id="dialogYB1W7" style="background: red;">
 <div id="text1">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text1">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text1">bla bla bla</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="description1AO2" style="background: green;">
 <div id="text1">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text2">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text3">bla bla bla</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="description4T6W" style="background: blue;">
 <div id="text1">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text2">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text3">bla bla bla</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="dialogB3EW" style="background: yellow;">
 <div id="text1">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text2">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text3">bla bla bla</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="dialog1L2A" style="background: red;">
 <div id="text1">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text2">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text3">bla bla bla</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="descriptionY3L1" style="background: green;">
 <div id="text1">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text2">bla bla bla</div>
 <div id="text3">bla bla bla</div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

**References**

[Substring matching attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings)